# C# WinForms MDI problem

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

Hello guyes i have one problem i have 1 parent form and 3 children i just want to open them maximized but when i do that in left side comes this 3 controls. How can i open one form without this controls.
If im doing this with wrong way please advice me something does mdi good for such things?

please see this pictures http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/6831/mdinz.jpg
http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/4687/mdi1.jpg

Comment: I guess there is something wrong, but some code would help, how you call the child form there is 1 MDI form here? when you mean 3 controls you mean the maximize,minimize .. buttons?

Comment: I can appreciate from the screenshots that English probably isn't your first language, but it would be helpful if you could state your question a lot more clearly. What is the problem in the screenshots?

Comment: Yes i mean maximize minimize and close. this is code :   Inventory invent = new Inventory();
            invent.MdiParent = this;
            invent.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            invent.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            invent.Show();

Comment: invent.MdiParent = this...is "this" child of another parent mdi form? I guess you can avoid these buttons unless you use some 3rd party tools. I use DevExpress XtraTabMdiContainer for these kind of jobs. Only problem i can see in your sample is that there are the 3 buttons 3 times!? 1 for main form,1 for parent? and the last for child. So you main form is other than the MDI Parent form!???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug in the MDI implementation, triggered when you create a maximized child window in the parent constructor.  This is an example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var child = new Form2();
        child.MdiParent = this;
        child.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        child.Show();
    }
}
```

You'll see the min/max/restore glyphs displayed twice, restoring the child window leaves the MDI bar on the screen, just as in your first screen shot.  The workaround is to move the child creation code to the OnLoad() method.  Like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        var child = new Form2();
        child.MdiParent = this;
        child.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        child.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ControlBox, FormBorderStyle, MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` properties to remove the various window UI elements from a form, if you wish.